# Amps and AmpHr?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, amperage, ampere-hour

What's the difference between **7Amps and 7AH**, can someone give a simple explanation?
Every answer I find is not helping me, for a beginner how do you explain this?

Comment: It's cz you don't look properly. Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between 18 A & 18 Ah on a Battery](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/393711/whats-the-difference-between-18-a-18-ah-on-a-battery)

Answer (score 3):

> for a beginner how do you explain this?

Assume a tank is full of water, and there's a faucet attached to the tank. You can adjust the flow rate of the faucet: If you open it more, the tank will drain more quickly.

Now the Amp-Hour (i.e. charge) is the amount of water in the tank, the flow rate of the water is Amperes.

7 Amp-Hours means the source can support 7 Amps continuously for 1 hour or 1 Amp for 7 hours.  Amp-Hour ratings are specified at the rated current of the battery, so if you draw less than rated current you get an increase in capacity and if you draw more than rated current you get a decrease in capacity.

Comment: Just to add since the OP is a beginner: just because the capacity of a battery is 7AHr, does not mean at can safely and effectively put out the entire capacity. For one thing, most batteries will decrease voltage and/or increase internal resistance as they discharge, making it harder to get the last of the charge out. Second, many rechargeable batteries can be damaged if discharged too low; for example, a standard lead-acid (car) battery, if discharged below a certain point, will have its effective life greatly reduced.

Comment: Thank you, it helped